# ambiguous void name remains after removing one fo the using statements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I had a script that started with both

```
using UnityEngine
```

and

```
using System
```

which told me `Random` was used in both which was fair so I removed the

```
using System
```

line as I wasn't using it anyway but this still throws the same error. I've tried to restart Unity, restart Visual Studio, restart my computer. Every reasonable solution seemed to not achieve anything.

Comment: What *exactly* is the error message? Can you reproduce this in a minimal example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are two classes called `Random` in two different namespaces, you can specify which class you want to use (to get rid of the error) by adding an alias for one of them:

```
using Random = System.Random;
// or
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
```

The alias doesn't have to be the same as the name of the class, so you can create aliases like `UnityRandom`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use UnityEngine.Random in you code.